# Calling jQuery selectors in HTML links?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make these jQuery commands execute later through links in html:

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#2wa').click(function() {
                           $('#ownstream').hide();
                           $('#movstream').hide();                               
                           $('#2wastream').fadeIn();                               
                    });
                $(document).ready(function(){                      
                    $('#own').click(function() {
                            $('#2wastream').hide();
                            $('#movstream').hide();
                            $('#ownstream').fadeIn();
                            return false;
                    });
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#mov').click(function() {
                            $('#2wastream').hide();
                            $('#ownstream').hide();                                     
                            $('#movstream').fadeIn();
                            return false;
                    });
```

These three selector commands are supposed to hide two items and show one when the ID on their second line is shown, but nothing happens when I click on it. The links are formatted as such:

```
                        <a href="test/#" id="own">
```

and the elements that are shown/hidden as such:

```
                        <div id="ownstream"></div>
```

For these I have two problems: the links themselves are not causing any change to take place, and none of them are taking place when the page loads, causing all three elements to appear. How do I solve this? Also, should I be placing the jquery script in the head or below the body?

Comment: sounds like your JQuery isn't loaded. Put it before the actual code

Comment: any errors shown on the console ?

Comment: Nope, no errors shown or recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not propertly closing the `$(document).ready(function(){`
Second you only need one of those.. not one for each binding ..

Finally add a common class to the links, for example `stream-opener`

```
<a href="test/#" id="own" class="stream-opener"> 
<a href="test/#" id="mov" class="stream-opener">
```

and another on the elements that show/hide

```
<div id="ownstream" class="stream"></div>
<div id="movstream" class="stream"></div>
```

and use this one script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.stream-opener').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var targetStream = '#' + this.id + 'stream';
       $('.stream').hide().filter( targetStream ).fadeIn();
   });
});
```

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work. I have no other javascript libraries loaded in the page and jquery is loaded directly before in the header through <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" language="javascript"></script> .

Comment: @TylerKing, sorry. I used the wrong selector when binding the handler.. i had `.streamer` instead of `.stream-opener`. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should place your jquery script in your head tag.  Then you can use this code anywhere below it.

Make sure your anchor tags have the matching ID name like so:

```
<a href="" id="2wa">
```

And not:

```
<a href="" class="2wa">
```

And for the links to hide on load, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#2wastream').hide();
    $('#ownstream').hide();                                     
});
```

Or add a css style attribute like so:

```
    <a href="" id="2wastream" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: Would this have sufficed?  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" language="javascript"></script>         This is loaded before the code linewise, but nothing is happening.

Comment: That will only work if you have that jquery file on your server.  Otherwise, try linking to the publically available one here:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js

Comment: Also, try opening the Web Developer console while running this page in Firefox (F12).  If this helped, please mark this as the answer, thanks!

Comment: Is it necessary to have <a href=""> be blank?

Comment: Nope, the href can be the URL you want or it can be a javascript function like so: `<a href="javascript:runFunction();">` or it can be blank entirely: `<a href="#">` or `<a href="javascript:void(0);">`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try to get this working.

Be sure your script is being pulled into the page, one way to check is by using the 'sources' tab in the Chrome Debugger and searching for the file else in the html head section

Be sure that you've included the datatale script after you've included jQuery, as it is most certainly dependant upon that.

Check whether jQuery is included properly and once only.

Watch out for jQuery conflicts. There is some other library which is overridding $, so your code is not working because $ is not an alias for jQuery anymore. You can use jQuery.noConflict() to avoid conflicts with other libraries on the page which use the same variable $.

According to your code why not pull all the code into one document.ready and close it correcly as below

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('#2wa').click(function() {
                           $('#ownstream').hide();
                           $('#movstream').hide();                               
                           $('#2wastream').fadeIn();                               
                    });


                    $('#own').click(function() {
                            $('#2wastream').hide();
                            $('#movstream').hide();
                            $('#ownstream').fadeIn();
                            return false;
                    });


                    $('#mov').click(function() {
                            $('#2wastream').hide();
                            $('#ownstream').hide();                                     
                            $('#movstream').fadeIn();
                            return false;
                    });
});
```

Lastly make sure that elements(2wastream, ownstream, movstream) that you refer actually exists with the ids.

Comment: If I'm using style="display:none;" to hide elements on startup, will .fadein(); override the style code?